# Customizing WordPress Widget with custom CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, widget

New to wordpress, just realizing when I register a new sidebar widget it WP creates the markup and css for it. I have created a widget with ID `recentposts`.

- I am also using the Widget CSS Classes Plugin to give the class name to the widget in dashboard. Here is what is looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7fVL.jpg
- Here is what the wordpress version (using the wordpress PHP dynamic_sidebar() function): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRszy.jpg [IT DOESN'T USE MY CSS - CREATES NEW MARKUP]
- Here IS MY version non-wordpress - what is should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4jQU.jpg
- POTENTIAL SOLUTION is to do an inspect element and find out the wordpress html markup css/id and change that, however it seems unnecessary. **What is the standard way of styling word press widgets with your css by default?**

**Problem: Trying to use my designed css, here is my version of the two widgets (html and css mockup)**

**HTML FOR RECENT POSTS (my version)**

```
    <div class="recent-post-wrap">
        <h3 id="recent-post-headline">RECENT POSTS:</h3>
        <ul class="recent-posts">
            <a href="#"><li> 10 Reasons to Finish</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li> How to Win Clients</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li> Increase management effeciency</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li> 3 Tips to manage people</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li> Project Manegement 101</li></a>
        </ul>               
    </div>
```

**CSS FOR RECENT POSTS (my version)**

```
    /* RECENT POST */
    .recent-post-wrap {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;      
    }

    /* list */
    .recent-post-wrap ul {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .recent-post-wrap ul li {
        padding: 2%;
    }
    .recent-post-wrap a:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }


    #recent-post-headline {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
```

***Now here is the WORDPRESS version***
html (wordpress)

```
            <div class="recent-post-wrap">
            <h3 id="recent-post-headline">RECENT POSTS:</h3>
            <ul class="recent-posts">

                <?php 
                    // If the sidebar widget is active i.e. in the admin a widget is been created then show the dynamic sidebar in the markup otherwise waste of markup.
                        if(is_active_sidebar('recentpost')) { 
                            dynamic_sidebar('recentpost');
                        } 
                ?>

            </ul>               
        </div>
```

**EDIT: HTML Output of WordPress**

```
<div class="recent-post-wrap">
            <h3 id="recent-post-headline">RECENT POSTS:</h3>
            <ul class="recent-posts">

                        <li id="recent-posts-3" class="widget widget_recent_entries">       <h2 class="widgettitle">Recent Posts</h2>
    <ul>
                <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2017/07/30/asdfads/">asdfads</a>
                    </li>
                <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2017/07/29/blog-post-two/">Title 2</a>
                    </li>
                <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2017/07/29/how-to-manage-your-team-effectively/">TITLE 1</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </li>

            </ul>               
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the HTML output of the WordPress version and have you inspected your site to check WordPress isn't overwriting your styles or that yours are actually being applied?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I've added the wordpress html output in the question, does this help? Also in your experience how do you handle css design on widgets e.x. inspect element find out the class wordpress as given or something else?

Comment: I normally just use the WordPress class and create my own CSS based on this. If I need something more specific I will add a custom class and then Inspect it and build my CSS that way. I would inspect your HTML on your site and just see if anything is being overwritten

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you want to override the styling furnished by the theme in your WordPress installation. That's very common. Almost everybody uses the browser Inspect Element function to work out the necessary CSS selectors to do that. Why? Because WordPress hasn't attempted to standardize theme CSS, and every theme is different. It's not clear why you don't want to use Inspect Element. But refusing to do so when customizing WP styling is like crossing a highway with your eyes closed.